# share content (disable user to edit the content)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Normally sharing the content by using the code below :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Possible to disable the content or skip the content send the content directly ?
Because the content is result from system, So only allow user to share the content but not able to edit. some expert know how to do that ? any good suggestion ?

Comment: What's you mean "skip the content send the content directly"? Do you want to share the content to a specific app?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT mean when share the content, the content is generate by system, not allow user to change the content.

Comment: The content you said  means "This is my text to send"?

Comment: yes. example the "This is my text to send." is generate by system. So not allow user to edit.